# How to call soap web service from php

Tags: php, soap

I am able to consume soap web service using wizdler in my chrome but need to how can I consume it in my php code.
From Wizdler I can get the proper response, for example I am posting the information like this:
[image]

Question is how to call this service from php code, what I did/trying so far is:

```
<?php

$wsdl = "http://64.20.37.90/VTWebServiceTest/VisualService.svc?wsdl";

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);

$request_param = array(

    "storeNumber" => "valid value",
    "enterpriseId" => "valid value",
    "credential" => "valid value"

);

try {

    $responce_param = $client->GetCategories($request_param);
    $result = $responce_param->GetCategoriesResult;
    print_r($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo "Exception Error!";
    echo $e->getMessage();

}

?>
```

But it always returns message "12|Invalid service credential."

Can anybody help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Invalid service credential" probably meand that your credentials are invalid. How sure you are that you are using valid parameters? Did you test the SOAP call in another way like using SoapUI?

Comment: I think Felippe is correct , I tried this is SOAPUI and get the same error. 
 I think this needs a valid value .... "credential" => "valid value"

Comment: Thanks Felippe and Mike. By using chrome extension "wizdler" to call the api, I can get the proper response as expected. I am guessing there is problem with request format while sending request through SoapClient. As you can see in my question there is Envelop passed through Wizdler. I am not sure what request format SoapClient is going to accept. I even tried by sending it XML but no luck.

Comment: Filippe, so I am sure the credentials are valid. But as it says "12|Invalid service credential." its mean its not reading the parameters because its not being provided in the way it is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe try this ...

```
$responce_param = $client->GetCategories($request_param);
print_r($responce_param);
```

or even

```
$responce_param = $client->GetCategories($request_param);
$values = get_object_vars($responce_param);
$myresults = object_to_array($values);
print_r($myresults);
```